# How to put one by one call on hold?

Tags: android

i trying put all incoming call for hold call.
All hold call listen voice call during incoming call.
voice call listen receiver side.but not found this code please do help?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Unless you want to do this programmatically, it belongs on [Android.SE].